# MongoDB Incorrect Results

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo DB Collection:

Each date (for example 2013-03-16) can have 3 country values: IND , US and SA, as shown below:

```
{
    "name": "SAM",
    "collection": [
        {
            "date": "2013-03-16",
            "country": "IND",
            "values": [
                {
                    "price": "24.0",
                    "gece": "342.1",
                    "countrycode": "IN"
                },
                {
                    "price": "24.0",
                    "gece": "322.1",
                    "countrycode": "IN"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-03-16",
            "country": "US",
            "values": [
                {
                    "price": "10.0",
                    "gece": "342.1",
                    "countrycode": "US"
                },
                {
                    "price": "120.0",
                    "gece": "342.1",
                    "countrycode": "US"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-03-16",
            "country": "SA",
            "values": [
                {
                    "price": "12.0",
                    "gece": "432.1",
                    "country": "SA"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-03-17",
            "country": "IND",
            "values": [
                {
                    "price": "10.0",
                    "gece": "532.1",
                    "country": "IN"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-03-17",
            "country": "US",
            "values": [
                {
                    "price": "38.0",
                    "gece": "332.1",
                    "country": "US"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using below code to test the structure:

```
  BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        query.put("name", "SAM");
        query.put("collection.date", "2013-03-17");
        query.put("collection.country", "IND");
        BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
        fields.put("name", 1);
        fields.put("collection.$", 1);
```

I am querying with date 2013-03-17, but it is returning data for 2013-03-16.

Here was the response:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "513121ac0651150e227d2224"
    },
    "name": "SAM",
    "collection": [
        {
            "date": "2013-03-16",
            "country": "IND",
            "values": [
                {
                    "price": "24.0",
                    "gece": "342.1",
                    "countrycode": "IN"
                },
                {
                    "price": "24.0",
                    "gece": "322.1",
                    "countrycode": "IN"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Why is it returning the wrong data for the date I give it?**

**Please see the edited part**

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
DBCollection mycollection = db.getCollection("xxx");


  BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("name", "SAM");
    query.put("collection.date", "2013-03-16");
    query.put("collection.country", "IND");
    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
    fields.put("name", 1);
    fields.put("collection.$", 1);

    BasicDBObject subquery = new BasicDBObject();
    subquery.put("date", "2013-03-16");
    subquery.put("country", "IND");
    query.put("collection", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", subquery));


DBCursor cursor = mycollection.find(query);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Still i am getting all the results

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "513121ac0651150e227d2224"} , "name" : "SAM" , "collection" : [ { "date" : "2013-03-16" , "country" : "IND" , "values" : [ { "price" : "24.0" , "gece" : "342.1" , "countrycode" : "IN"} , { "price" : "24.0" , "gece" : "322.1" , "countrycode" : "IN"}]} , { "date" : "2013-03-16" , "country" : "US" , "values" : [ { "price" : "10.0" , "gece" : "342.1" , "countrycode" : "US"} , { "price" : "120.0" , "gece" : "342.1" , "countrycode" : "US"}]} , { "date" : "2013-03-16" , "country" : "SA" , "values" : [ { "price" : "12.0" , "gece" : "432.1" , "country" : "SA"}]} , { "date" : "2013-03-17" , "country" : "IND" , "values" : [ { "price" : "10.0" , "gece" : "532.1" , "country" : "IN"}]} , { "date" : "2013-03-17" , "country" : "US" , "values" : [ { "price" : "38.0" , "gece" : "332.1" , "country" : "US"}]}]}
```

Comment: One thing to check ... are the dates stored as UTC (yet your search is not?)

Answer (score 3):

Your query is only allowed to contain **one** array field if you want to use the [positional $ operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/#_S_).

Your query should look something along these lines:

```
BasicDBObject subquery = new BasicDBObject();
subquery.put("date", "2013-03-17");
subquery.put("country", "IND");
query.put("collection", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", subquery));
```

Comment: I tried the above program , but i was getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.LinkedHashMap$EntryIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)

Comment: @PreethiJain Replace the last `subquery.put` with `query.put` in your code so it matches @nutlike's answer.

Comment: @PreethiJain You need to pass `fields` into your `find` call as the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks Johnny , that works perfect as expected . Thank you very much .